# iPhone zoomed way in on website

Tags: php, iphone, html, css

Been working on this for a few hours but can't seem to figure out what it is.  The website is zoomed in for some reason and I can't figure it out.  Here is my meta tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1030, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I'm thinking it may be a css issue though.  The site is [here](http://ghcnow.com/)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you change 'initial-scale' to something else?  Say ... 0.2?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difficult to test but you are using fixed values in that meta tag and possibly in the CSS file:

1. Try replacing that meta tag with

   ```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
   ```
2. Make sure you are using % and not px pt etc. in your CSS

Comment: I tried the meta tag and got the same results. Does everything in the CSS have to be in percentages or just the divs?  For example, if I want an image to have a width of 320px will that effect the layout on a mobile device?

Comment: Tricky. Use them as far as possible but be wary that at some point fixed widths like images will be too big for the container divs. Us media queries to swap out the imagery or use http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/ (be wary of older browsers though)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method (best used for all devices):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a responsive design it's better if you just delete the meta tag.